# Luna ISO needed

Tags: luna, iso

I was able to run Luna well off on an old PC. But the stable release Freya is lagging making it unusable. I don't have the ISO for Luna to go back to the old state. Could anyone tell me where I could find one?

Comment: Luna is not supported and not available anymore from official sources and seems absent on the web. Are you sure that Luna is a solution for you? (I had better experience with Freya than with Luna on the same computer). Have you tested Luna already on that pc? If you are sure that what you need is a 12.04 Ubuntu-based system, that is [still supported till 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS/), which I'm sure is a better way to go than using an outdated and unsupported OS. You could try [Lubuntu 12.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/) and possibly customize that.

Comment: What you should test first is whether you really need a 12.04-based system instead of a 14.04 system. You should  try a 14.04-based system with a light desktop like LXDE (Lubuntu): maybe your problem is with the resources required by the desktop environment and not with those required by the newer ubuntu/kernel version. A pc that can run Luna will very well run even Xubuntu/Xfce 12.04 or even 14.04. - If **really** your problem is that you cannot run 14.04 ubuntu-based systems, you have a choice between different systems that still use the 12.04, but Luna seems not to be one of them.

Comment: See my answer on http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/where-can-i-download-luna/7237#7237